# Cordova camera plugin: Photo is not displayed when taking a picture

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using the Cordova camera plugin and i have encountered a problem.

When using :
`sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY` I get a this url: `content://media/external/images/media/1517`

When using this url on `<img ng-src="{{image}}" alt="Description"/>`
everything works great

But when removing the `sourceType` and taking a picture with the phone the returned URI is something like this:
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.myapp/cache/1454450218633.jpg`

And when this URI is returning the image is not displayed.
Any ideas? its on ionic framework and on android device.

Some code This is for taking the picture:

```
   function takePhoto() {
     var defer = $q.defer();

     navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) {
       defer.resolve(imageData);
     }, function(err) {
       defer.reject(err)
     });

     return defer.promise;
   }
```

This method is being called from:

```
$scope.getImage = function() {
  cameraService.takePhoto().then(function(imageData){
    console.log(imageData);
    $scope.image = imageData;
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

and the provider whitelist:

```
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|blob|cdvfile|content):|data:image\//);
```

UPDATE:

I was able to get it done by using `Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`
But isn't it possible to only take the file url and display the image?
Again it is working when selecting the photo from library but not when taking new one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the `livereload` feature.
Running the application without livereload and then your able to load picuters from that path

Comment: Same for me, and then I discovered the issue. But there's not a way to see the picture also in livereload?